# make: *** No rule to make target 'main.c', needed by 'main.o'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 .c files in my src directory and i have a Makefile in the parent directory of src. All my c files just use standard header files.
The error i am getting while using make command is

> make: *** No rule to make target 'main.c', needed by 'main.o'.  Stop.

I tried all the tweaks that people have mentioned here and there but could not solve the problem. help please.

i tried including vpath directive too.

## **Makefile**

```
vpath src
vpath inc
CFLAGS=-I inc
output: main.o helloExec.o execDemo.o
    $(CC) -o $(CFLAGS) $<

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(CFLAGS)
helloExec.o: helloExec.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(CFLAGS)
execDemo.o: execDemo.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(CFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f *.o output
```

## **main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

## **execDemo.c**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("execDemo with pid = %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

## **helloExec.c**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("helloExec with pid = %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`VPATH` is a [variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html).

So, it should be in upper case, and set to a list of directories:

```
VPATH=src:inc
```

Comment: Or if you want to use `vpath` you have to provide a pattern: `vpath %.c src` and `vpath %.h inc`; see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html

Comment: The `vpath` directive seems to be specific to GNU make, unlike the `VPATH` variable which also exists in other `make` programs.

Comment: It's true that some other makes might implement `VPATH` but it's not part of the POSIX standard so there's no guarantee that it will work the same way, or even exist, across them all... it's inherently non-portable.

Answer (score -1):

The output build line `$(CC) -o $(CFLAGS) $<` is incorrect:
what follows the `-o` option is the output (executable) file.

```
CFLAGS=-Iinc

output: main.o helloExec.o execDemo.o
    $(CC) $< -o output

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(CFLAGS)

helloExec.o: helloExec.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(CFLAGS)

execDemo.o: execDemo.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o output
```

Comment: Although this answer is not related to the question being asked, the observation is quite correct (although the solution provided here is missing `$(CFLAGS)` on the link line which is not right),

Comment: why do you think $(CFLAGS) is needed on link line? There is no compilation, only linking taking place.

Comment: Because `CFLAGS` often contains flags that DO make a difference for linking, such as `-pthread`.  In general it's good practice to pass the compiler flags to the link step as well.

Comment: In this question where the only thing in `CFLAGS` is `-I`, the user should most correctly be using `CPPFLAGS` for that not `CFLAGS`; preprocessor options like `-I` and `-D` are typically added to `CPPFLAGS` so that they can be passed to other tools like lint, etc. that need to run the preprocessor but not the compiler.

Comment: @MadScientist, then why not use `$(LDFLAGS)` which is more oriented to pass link options.  You can include things like `-pthreads` at compiling and at linking.... :)

Comment: It's your makefile you can put your flags wherever you want :)... you don't even have to use these names if you don't want to.  I'm just telling you that "standard practice" in makefiles is to put C compiler flags in `CFLAGS`, put preprocessor flags in `CPPFLAGS`, and put linker-only flags in `LDFLAGS`, and pass both `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` to the linker (assuming you're using the compiler front-end, as you should be, and not invoking `ld` directly).  Maybe your linker front-end cares about optimization, debug, or something else, or maybe not... why worry about it?